# Reduce vertical space after list of algorithms' title

Tags: lists, algorithms

I would like to control the spacing after and before the list of algorithms title to fit all the algorithms in one page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,headsepline,a4paper,BCOR=10mm,twoside,titlepage,pdftex,cleardoubleplain]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english,ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage


\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\newpage

\input{chapters/chapter1}
\input{chapters/chapter2}
\appendix
\input{chapters/Appendix}
\listofalgorithms
\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{library}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't do this, since there is no consistency with other chapter titles, but if you really want to do this, here is what you can do.

You have two commands to control the spacing before and after the chapter titles, `\chapterheadstartvskip` and `\chapterheadendvskip`, respectively.

You can modify them locally to change only the appearance of the List of Algorithms:

```
\begingroup
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-80pt}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace*{0pt}}
\listofalgorithms
\endgroup
```

In this way, all other chapters are not affected by this change.

The following MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,headsepline,a4paper,BCOR=10mm,twoside,titlepage,pdftex,cleardoubleplain]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english,ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\begin{document}
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage


\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\newpage

\begingroup
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-80pt}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\vspace*{0pt}}
\listofalgorithms
\endgroup

\chapter{a chapter}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{An algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

yields this result for the LoA page:

[image]

Adjust the above parameters to fit your needs.